# Issue with running open CV face detection on Mac mountain lion

Tags: c++, c, macos, opencv

I ran into an issue getting the standard open CV face detection (`facedetect`) working.  The web cam light comes on but noting happens, the program is launched with a tiny sized window like this:

[image]

I am working from an [excellent blog post](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) and [sample code](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training).  Here I what I have done:

1. Install OpenCV & get OpenCV source

   ```
   brew tap homebrew/science
   brew install --with-tbb opencv
   wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.6/opencv-2.4.6.tar.gz
   tar xvzf opencv-2.4.6.tar.gz
   ```
2. Run the `facedetect` sample with the standard classifier.

   ```
   cd ~/opencv-2.4.6/samples/c
   chmod +x build_all.sh
   ./build_all.sh
   ./facedetect --cascade="../../data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
   ```

I can modify the C++ sample code and recompile and run, but I have no idea what the issue is.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

*Update* The issue is the image from `cvQueryFrame` is empty:

```
IplImage* iplImg = cvQueryFrame( capture );
frame = iplImg;
if( frame.empty() ) 
{
    cout << "FRAME EMPTY\n";  // This is getting logged
    break;
}
```

*Update*: It works ok when the source is a static image, so the issue is something related to the webcam source.

[image: Lena]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to localise the problem, did you try to capture an image from the and web cam show it, without running any other operation?

It seems there is a problem capturing image from the web cam via OpenCV, this kind of problems may happen due to hardware, for instance on my friends macbook pro captured image was 320x240 and on mine it was 640x480. My friend just changed a simple configuration from settings of the camera and his problem was solved. Your problem might be something like this.

Or you can try to run face detector just with some images, you need to change the code such that it loads an image from your disk and try to detect face on them. If it doesn't work that way either we can say that your problem is not camera, there is a bigger issue, or if it works we can surely say that the problem is web cam.

**EDIT**

If you are using IplImage type be sure to get couple more images from the camera, sometimes first image is empty.

Comment: Nice tip, I got good old lena working! :) http://i.imgur.com/2rv5Cxd.png  So the issue is with the webcam / hardware.  Do you remember any details about the settings configuration change your friend did?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember, but I think you can try to use external webcam? All you need to do is plug it from USB and change your code such that you initialise the `cv::Capture` with device id 1 instead of 0 (which is default).

Comment: And I also found an [application](https://itunes.apple.com/tr/app/webcam-settings/id533696630?mt=12) for camera preferences but not sure if it'll work for you..

Comment: Another thing that you can try is to capture image from camera and before displaying it, write it to the disk using `cv::imwrite`, because your problem might only be displaying not capturing. So, if it can write the image to disk correctly your problem is not webcam :)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added some logging and and the issue is with `cvQueryFrame`, it returns an empty `IplImage` (I have updated my question).  The problem is more isolated now :)

Comment: I want to say one last thing, if you are not have to please don't use old C API and use much more better C++ API, even that might help you overcome your problem. `cv::Mat frame; cv::Capture capture(0); capture >> frame;` this is all the code you need in order to get image from camera. This is much more better then using `IplImage` and `cvQueryFrame`. Hope you can solve your problem soon :)

Comment: One last quesiton - how do you know if its the old or new API?  Is `IplImage` part of the old API?  Does the new API use `cv::Mat` for images instead of `IplImage`s?

Comment: Yes that's true.. All the classes you use should be under opencv2 not opencv if you want you C++ API (I'm talking about the include file). For instance, `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>`. And from your post it can be clearly seen that you are using C API since your path is /opencv-2.4.6/samples/c, try cpp instead of c. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

This was due to a bug in OpenCV - its been fixed ( bug report here http://code.opencv.org/issues/3156) , but the version in homebrew/science is from before the fix.

You can get install a newer version by editing the brew formula for opencv ( based on this pull request https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/pull/540 )

edit /usr/local/Library/Formula/opencv.rb , and replace these lines:

```
url 'http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.4.6.1/opencv-2.4.6.1.tar.gz'
sha1 'e015bd67218844b38daf3cea8aab505b592a66c0'
```

with these ones

```
url 'https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/2.4.7.1.tar.gz'
sha1 'b6b0dd72356822a482ca3a27a7a88145aca6f34c'
```

Then do

```
brew remove opencv 
brew install opencv
```

Works on Mavericks (for me at least), *should* work on Mountain Lion

UPDATE: the version of OpenCV in homebrew/science has now been updated, so this answer is now out of date!

```
brew upgrade opencv
```

will make homebrew get the latest version, with fixed webcam capture.